# Replace jumping with sliding and then change modes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was tasked with creating an animation in javascript using an existing code and altering to do two things. Switch modes, and go on until the person closes the program. The four modes are:

mode 0 - left to right

mode 1 - top to bottom

mode 2 - right to left

mode 3 - bottom to top

Switching from mode 0 - 1 is where the trouble starts. It's supposed to slide, but it jumps when I get there.

Below is my code as is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            background: yellow;
        }
        #animate {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: red;
        }
     </style>
     <body>

     <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

     <div id ="container">
         <div id ="animate"></div>
     </div>

     <script>
         function myMove() {
             var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
             var pos = 350;
             var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
         }
         function frame() {
             if (pos == 0) {
                 pos++;
                 elem.style.bottom= pos + 'px';
             } else {
                 pos--;
                 elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 

                 if (pos == 49.985) {
                     pos++;
                     elem.style.left = pos + "px";
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question. This also doesn't look to have anything to do with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use two variables for both x and y, and replace posBottom with a variable for top style.

The issue before was that when `pos` was equal to 0 and thus triggered the if statement, it immediately incremented, causing it to instead trigger the `else`, and then decremented, going back to `if`, and so on. It jumped because the `style.bottom = 0px` was causing it to go straight down to the bottom.

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var posLeft = 350;
  var posTop = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (posLeft == 0 && posTop != 350) {
      stage=1;
      posTop++;
      elem.style.top= posTop + 'px';
    } else if (posTop == 0) {
      posLeft--;
      elem.style.left = posLeft + "px"; 
    } else if (posLeft != 350) {
      posLeft++;
      elem.style.left = posLeft + "px";
    } else if (posTop != 0) {
      posTop--;
      elem.style.top= posTop + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {

  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```